# Access new session_id at the end of login action

Tags: php, codeigniter

Consider the following code:

```
function authenticate(){
    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', true);
}
```

How do I return this users session_id from the `authenticate` function? It's not available from the session class until the page is refreshed.

Comment: Does it use the normal session-functionality (I don't work with CI)? 'cause in that case, you could just use `session_id()`.

Comment: Also: do you really need to return said `session_id`? The session class is designed to save the pain and suffering involved with keeping track of raw session data by yourself.

Comment: Yeah I do need to return session_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
    $this->load->library('session');
    echo $this->session->userdata('session_id');


function authenticate(){
    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', true);
return $this->session->userdata('session_id');
}
```

Comment: Yes, and as I described in my question the session class does not update itself until the next page refresh.

Comment: I suppose session_id is generated once you load the session library and then will remain the same after you call your authenticate? Unless you use session_regenerate or something like it. I am not sure though.

Comment: Nevermind. I was calling sess_destroy() and it doesnt update even after you set_userdata() after that call, I guess.